# MySQL count occurrences of data displayed as list in cells

Tags: mysql, replace, count

Good day all.
Lets say that I've a table organized like this:

```
|ColA         |
---------------
|AAA            |
|AAA#!#BBB      |
|BBB#!#CCC#!#DDD|
|AAA#!#DDD      |
|DDD            |
```

What I would like to achieve is to count occurrences of every string, considering the simbols "#!#" as a separator.
The best should be having a MySQL `Count()` result style:

```
|count|   |
|AAA  |3  |
|BBB  |2  |
|CCC  |1  |
|DDD  |3  |
```

Is it possible to combine a `replace` with a `count` in a SQL statement? is it possible to use the `replace` result as a table to apply the `count` on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
    (`id` int, `ColA` varchar(255));    
INSERT INTO TableA
    (`id`, `ColA`)
VALUES
    (1, 'AAA'),
    (2, 'AAA#!#BBB'),
    (3, 'BBB#!#CCC#!#DDD'),
    (4, 'AAA#!#DDD'),
    (5, 'DDD');


CREATE TABLE TableB
    (`id` int, `Name` varchar(255));    
INSERT INTO TableB
    (`id`, `Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'AAA'),
    (2, 'BBB'),
    (3, 'CCC'),
    (4, 'DDD');
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT col, SUM(count) as count 
FROM
  (SELECT
      t2.Name as col,
      ROUND (   
          (
              CHAR_LENGTH(t1.ColA)
              - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE (t1.ColA, t2.Name, "") ) 
          ) / CHAR_LENGTH(t2.Name)        
      ) as count    
  FROM TableA as t1
  INNER JOIN TableB as t2) as SubB 
GROUP BY col, count
HAVING count > 0;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c76c/1)**

Comment: nice and tricky, the main issue is that in this case I should know all the possible values of the colA, to create the TableB, unluckily the values are unpredictable, or at least a number that can't be easily used as input for the table B, think it as every entry should be a province name, in a table that could contain every province of a state, or something like this.

Comment: indeed that should be a way, for now, it is a way :) thanks for the time spent. :)